# martingale and stopping time

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

I currently learn martingale and I am confused on martingale with a stopping time.

Dobb's optional stopping says that if $T$ is bounded, $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale, then $E[X_T] = E[X_0]$.

I have two questions:

1. Stopping time $T$ is a random variable and $X_n$ is also a random variable. But how to understand $X_T$?
2. $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale so $\{X_n\}$ have the same expectation already. What's the fancy part of Dobb's optional stopping? I mean why it is important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) $X_{T}$ is given by $X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$. (2) Note that the result doesn't hold if $T$ is unbounded. Consider simple symmetric random walk with $T = \inf(n: X_{n} = 2)$ for example.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse $X_T$ with the stopped process $X_{T\wedge n}$, which is sometimes denoted $X^T$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $X_T : \omega\in\Omega \mapsto X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)\in\mathbb{R}$ ;
2. $T$ is random, but whatever value it takes, on average, $X_T$ will have the same value as $X_0$ (on average...).